# UK Covid-19 Testing for travelers from the US

Tags: uk, covid-19

I understand from the gov.uk site that fully vaccinated travelers from the US need to book a "Day 2" test prior to arrival in the UK. The https://www.find-travel-test-provider.service.gov.uk/test-type/green list of providers indicates that the prices are very inexpensive, starting from 1.25 GBP, but clicking on the links indicates that the tests are actually 49 GBP and up. I did see one provider covidtestingdirect.com has appointments at the IBIS Heathrow Testing Center for 0.45 GBP.  Has anyone used this service? Why pay the extra $66, just for the convenience of getting the test in the mail?

Comment: Test by mail is going to be expensive. Test at site is cheap but you may not get any appointments.

Comment: I suspect bait&switch, but don't see exactly how. One provider offers "standard service" for 0.45 GBP, and "premium service" for 89GBP, with no explanation of the difference. I suspect that they expect to push customers to premium, possibly via lack of standard appointments.

Comment: Yes Aak, you are right. Whenever I tried to make an appointment for the almost free in person test, it said they were booked up. Even the less expensive mail in tests were sold out.  I clicked through most of the list. Bait & switch it is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.